# Calling a props provided method that uses react-router properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this issue. I was wondering if someone here would be able to take a look? I have a component that I'm passing a method called `this.fetchContent` to as props called Filter. `this.fetchContent` fires an action creator that uses axios via Redux to get some data from an API, I pass it the current page location using react-router via`this.props.params`.

The issue occurs with calling the method from the child component. What I've done is bound `this.props.fetchContent` to an onClick handler inside the Filter component. Whenever I click the `<Link />` tag the function fires, and the page route gets updated. However the value of the parent components `props` doesn't update until *after* the function has fired, causing only every other click to produce the correct API call.

**App:**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.fetchContent = this.fetchContent.bind(this);
  }
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchContent();
  }

  fetchContent() {
    let query = `${this.props.params.sub}/${this.props.params.filter}`;
    this.props.fetchList(query, this.props.location.search);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Filter 
          filter={this.props.params.filter}
          sub={this.props.params.sub}
          search={this.props.location.search}
          fetchContent={this.fetchContent} />
          {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Filter**

```
class Filter extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                <div className="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
                    <Link to={`/r/${this.props.sub}/new/${this.props.search}`} onClick={this.props.fetchContent}>
                        <span className="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Hot</span>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>  
        )
    }
}
```

I understand what's happening here but I'm not sure what the React-friendly way of solving this issue is. How can I re-factor my code to produce the results I need and what are the best practices for solving this sort of issue?

**Edit:** Updated the syntax but still seeing the same issue.

Comment: ` However the value of the parent components props doesn't update until after the function has fired` How are you passing the props to parent and how is the props gets updated ?

Comment: why do you need to wrap this in another function `fetchContent={() => this.fetchContent}` while you can write it like `fetchContent={this.fetchContent}`

Comment: @Panther react-router is updating props on the parent. I adjusted the syntax and still see the issue. `this.props.params` doesn't update until after `this.fetchContent` gets called, resulting in the props argument of my action creator being out of date.

Comment: i really cant see where your props are getting updated ? I think you are mentioning about `props.params` in `app`, but where or how is it getting updated ? Can you brief that part ?

Comment: When the route changes props gets passed from React Router

Comment: That is what.. as far as i see.. there no route change! How do u change the route ?

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax mistake I believe. You are executing the function rather than returning it.

This

```
<Link to={`/r/${this.props.sub}/new/${this.props.search}`} onClick={this.props.fetchContent()}>
    <span className="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Hot</span>
</Link>
```

Should be like this;

```
<Link to={`/r/${this.props.sub}/new/${this.props.search}`} onClick={this.props.fetchContent}>
    <span className="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Hot</span>
</Link>
```

OR like this

```
<Link to={`/r/${this.props.sub}/new/${this.props.search}`} onClick={() => { this.props.fetchContent() }}>
    <span className="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Hot</span>
</Link>
```

**PS:** I believe you have a typo on App component since you don have a closing on Filter component at render.

Comment: Aha, cheers! I tried to over complicate things and wound up in a rut. :)

Comment: Although, after testing this, this doesn't solve the problem of the parent components props updating until after `this.fetchContent` has been called. Is there someway to wait for `this.props.params` to finish updating before finishing the function call?